# Oracle TO_DATE() function

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to insert date into an oracle database which is imported from an excel spreadsheet. At some rows of spreadsheet, the date is represented in 24 hour format and at some rows it is represented in AM/PM format.

I started converting the date string to oracle format by using TO_DATE function as

```
"TO_DATE(\'" + Timestamp + "\', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM', 'nls_date_language=american')"
```

The "Timestamp" here is a C# string variable which has date in string format.

I am getting exception when the timestamp variable is represented in 24 hour format. Is there any way that I can make my C# code accept both type of date formats and insert into oracle table as they are?

Comment: It would be easier to parse it on C# side and pass the proper value to DB function. Check out [DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @IvanKashtanov I tried DateTime.Parse() as DateTime.TryParseExact(Stall Timestamp.ToString(), "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date); to convert all the times into AM/PM format. But I am getting result as 01-JAN-01 12:00:00AM EST and not the exact time

Comment: DateTime parsedDate= DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @aspxsushil Sometimes I need to pass string with AM/PM format to the input date, then I am getting an exception for wrong format

Comment: @IvanKashtanov Can you please look at the way I tried and help me if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("8:00 AM");
            Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("HH:mm"));  This shall convert to 24 hour format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways you can go:

**C# (as suggested above)**

`DateTime.ParseExact` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_) that lets you pass multiple format strings. It will use the first one that works. `DateTime.TryParseExact` also has this overload. `DateTime.Parse` does not.

```
string[] formats = {"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"};
DateTime Timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

**Oracle**

Have Oracle check for AM or PM and adjust the format string accordingly. This is the raw Oracle; I'll leave the string building to you:

```
TO_DATE(val,
  CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(val, '(AM|PM)')
    THEN 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'
    ELSE 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
  END)
```

Any code issues let me know. I'm not at a machine where I could test these snippets.

Comment: Thanks. The Oracle way worked. I actually got this idea but wondering if there is an other way in which the oracle TO_DATE() works regardless of the format of the date string provided.

Comment: Glad it worked! I don't know of any way to have `TO_DATE` work without regard to the format string, and there's no equivalent of the C# `TryParse` that will let you specify multiple format strings. I'm sure there are other pure Oracle alternatives to my answer, but they'd likely be just as awkward and wordy.